# .zshrc inconsistent type for assignment?

Tags: bash, mongodb, zsh, zshrc

I install `MongoDB` by using `homebrew`

and set the path within `.zshrc`:

`export path=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.4.6/bin:$PATH`

But when I open the `iTerm2`, the `stdout` give me this:

```
Last login: Sat Jul 22 19:57:33 on ttys001
/Users/elsa/.zshrc:export:95: path: inconsistent type for assignment
```

what's this? how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lowercase **path** should be uppercase.

export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.4.6/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 9):

I got this when changing a value for JAVA17_HOME. Doing

```
unset JAVA17_HOME
```

and then setting it again worked.

Not the original problem, which was answered, but may help people who land here while searching.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32502234)

Comment: This actually answers the question of how to resolve the error in any context outside the original question.